# Accessing other model field when validating model field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

So I have a Django auctions app, which has 4 models: Users, Listings, Bids, Comments.

When a user tries to place a bid on some listing, I want to check whether `bid_amount` field in `Bid` model is smaller than start `starting_bid` field in `Listing` model. 
Also, I wanted to ask, what is the best practice for this kinda stuff? AFAIK, you can validate a form field in `forms.py`. 
Thanks!

**models.py**

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    """Auction listing"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='user owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="usr_listings")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=160)
    starting_bid = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    bids_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    img_url = models.URLField("Image URL", max_length=200, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    date_listed = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'auction listing'
        ordering = ['-date_listed']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        print('loading... get_absolute_url')
        return reverse('listing_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Bid(models.Model):
    """Bids made on auction listing"""
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listing_bids")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_bidder")
    bid_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Bid'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.bid_amount} by {self.user} on {self.listing}'

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        # do something to access Listing.starting bid, and Listing.user
```

Answer (score 0):

adding this to the `clean` method of `Bid` solve the problem for you.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

...

if self.bid_amount < self.listing.starting_bid:
    raise ValidationError("bid_amount must be greater than or equal to starting_bid of the listing")
```

Comment: tried that, throws an error ```auctions.models.Bid.listing.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Bid has no listing.```

Comment: How do you create `Bid`? I assumed you're providing an existing `Listing` when you create a new object.

Comment: there is a foreign key to the listing if that's what you mean

Comment: I mean if you create a `Bid` object with an already existing `Listing` object it should just work fine.
Let's say you do have a `Listing` object called `listing_obj` and you create a new `Bid` as follow: `Bid(listing=listing_obj, user=current_user, bid_amount=10).save()`

Comment: Okay and if the error is the one you mentioned, it means somewhere along the way you're providing a `Listing` object that does not exist in the database. Maybe you haven't called `save` yet!?

Comment: I'm getting this error when I'm trying to place a bid on an existing listing. I need to get this value to check ```bid_amount``` that I'm trying to place against ```starting_bid```